# Toad for Oracle 64-bit : 1603 - Fatal error during installation

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, toad

I'm trying to install Toad for oracle client, my Toad version is 12.1 for 64 bit system, i have succeeded to install oracle client 12c for 64 bit system, but i have stumbled by a problem when installing the Toad, the error is :

[image: Error message]

The content of the 'Toad for oracle 12.1 64bit.msi.lo' file is available via this link (beacause his size is big and we can not write it here):

[Toad for oracle 12.1 64bit.msi.lo](http://www.gulfup.com/?kyutXN)

Can anyone here help me please, Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is to few information available, The link does not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I get this error all the time with the installation or updgrade of the sql optimizer tool, For me this error is always due to the required VBSCRIPT.DLL and JSCRIPT.DLL files not being correctly registered.  Following the step listed here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/jscript/thread/b7d1a35f-3759-4217-91ba-e4416ac19d78
works for me.